# Rounding issue when adding certain floats

Tags: amazon-redshift

Addition of certain floats ends up with XXXX.XX00000000003

For Example:

```
convert(float,2896)+convert(float,268.98),
convert(float,2896)+convert(float,268.96),
convert(float,2896)+convert(float,168.97)
```

Resuts in:

```
3164.9700000000003  3164.98 3164.96 3064.97
```

I expected the first result to be 3164.97.  What gives?

Comment: Wow, I think that is it.  Thanks for that Robert!

Comment: @PaulKats If you agree that it's a duplicate, you can auto-mark the question as a duplicate or delete it to help keep folks directed to Robert's link as a resource